# jquery add/remove class and event

Tags: jquery

Okay so, i have a list with class "active" on each LI element.

```
<ul class="mylist">
<li class="active">Myval1</li><li class="active">MyVal</li>...
</ul>
```

And i want onclick on any of those li elements to change its class to "inactive"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".active").on("click", function(){
$(this).removeClass("active");$(this).addClass("inactive");
//second question code goes here <<<
});
});
```

and then not be able to click on it again unless its class is changed back to "active".
And this code works, but once an event handler is bound to an element it doesn't account the class change, meaning the class gets changed but even if is "inactive" you can still click on it and it works as it is "active".

*So my first question is how to do it, in such a way that after changing "active" to "inactive" you can't click it, unless its changed back to active?*

*My second question*:

```
var val=jQuery('.myinput').val();
          jQuery('.myinput').val(val+jQuery(this).text()+',');
```

This code is inside the on click function (from the first code) the question is, why when i click on element, it adds the value to the input but TWICE, so if I click on "myval" it adds  "myval,myval" on single click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are expecting something like this

```
$('body').on('click', 'li', '', function (e) {

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('inactive');


        var values = $(this).text();
        var strs = values.search("[x]");

        if (strs > 0) {
            var vals = values.replace("[x]", "");
            $('.mylist').append("<li class=active>" + vals + "<a class='removeme'>[x]</a>");
        } else {
            $('.mylist').append("<li class=active>" + values + "<a class='removeme'>[x]</a>");
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

$('body').on('click', 'a.removeme', '', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5tjQ4/4/)**

Comment: Well exactly, can you just add little [x] after newly added element, so i can delete it?

Comment: well it doesnt remove the items, but i get the idea now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[***JSFIDDLE DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/muralim/Lv67V/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on("click",".active", function(){
   console.log("now active -> inactive");
   $(this).toggleClass("active inactive"); 
   var val=jQuery('.myinput').val();
   jQuery('.myinput').val(val+jQuery(this).text()+',');
 });

 $(document).on("click",".inactive", function(e){
    console.log("still inactive. Do nothing");
    return false;
 });

});
```

Comment: This, although better logically, doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I can't see anything in cosole log, when i click on values...?

Comment: Okay, what about adding small [x] next to my val if "inactive" and if clicked it would become "active"? And also can you asnwer my second qeuestion, why does it trigger twice on single click (even with your code)?

Comment: @user3450125, please add your code in fiddle and let me know what you are trying. I am not getting your question clearly

Comment: The code you give me  works perfectly, now I just want to get the clicked LI element .text() (when it class active) and append it to another UL element, can you help me out?

Comment: @user3450125, see my updated answer. Is this the one you are expecting?

Comment: yeah but inside another ul, sorry i found that ul would be better for the [x] instead of input field, so yea the same idea but instead input field into UL with little [x] after the values so when user click on them they would disapear from input, and change their class in list to "active" .Like when adding tags on "question ask" form in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // All li elements in my .myList
    $(".myList > li").on("click", function() {

        // Store $(this) in a variable, better for performance memory, jadajada.
        var el = $(this);

        // If the element has class active and NOT inactive we can procede.
        if (el.hasClass('active') && !el.hasClass('inactive')) {

            // Remove active class and add inactive class
            el.removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");

            // Put code here that can only be activated when the class "active" is on the element.
        }

        // If this only needs to be fired when the active class in on the li add it in the if above.
        // Get current value
        var value = $('.myinput').val();

        // IF the value was FOO then the value would now become, "FOO Myval1,"
        value = value + el.text() + ',';

        // add the new value
        $('.myinput').val(value);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think This Will Help You :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".mylist").find('li').click(function () {
            var val = $('.myinput').val();
            if ($(this).attr('class') == 'active') {
                $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
                val += $(this).html() + ',';
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
                val = '';
                var ItemCount = $(".mylist").find('li.inactive');
                for (var i = 0; i < ItemCount.length; i++) {
                    val += $(ItemCount[i]).html() + ',';
                }
            }
            $('.myinput').val(val);
        });
    });
</script>
```